# How can I deploy (install) cakephp 3.0 project on a shared hosting server?

Tags: cakephp, deployment, installation, window

Sorry for my english. I made a cakephp 3.0 project locally (**wamp server - http://localhost/**) and I want to put on a shared hosting server. Locally everything works fine.
I transferred a project via **FTP to the server**. Unfortunately It displays a blank white window. PHP version on the shared hosting server is 5.6.
Permission on tmp folder is 777.
How to make installation? Please help!!!

Comment: What you see in your error.log? Is enabled intl extension on remote server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you set up cakephp on a shared hosting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580346/how-do-you-set-up-cakephp-on-a-shared-hosting)

Comment: Error log is empty. I don't know what is intl extension. Hosting is InfoNet (good hosting in Croatia). I believe that the hosting server is configured properly

Comment: @user3661042 intl extesion je php ekstenzija bez koje cakephp ne moze raditi, pogledaj sa phpinfo() je li ta ekstenzija uključena.

Comment: ok, kontaktirat ću hosting providera. da li se instalacija cakephp 3 radi putem FTP-a? Sve mi je ovo pomalo novo i zbunjujuće uključuju composere. Da sada sam sve radio putem FTP-a. Inače cakephp koristim još od verzije 1

Comment: Javi se ovdje https://kiwiirc.com/client/irc.freenode.net#cakephp Salines

Answer (score 0):

Put this lines in **app/index.php** file to show all errors

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", "on");
```

(overhead this line)

```
require 'webroot' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'index.php';
```

Comment: I enabled intl extension on remote server everything works fine now

Comment: Cool! @user3661042